# Optional character match regex

Tags: regex, perl, optional-values

I have a condition where my string could look like:

1. test23@testbee:/var/bee/

or

2. testbee:/var/bee/test.html

I need to extract three string here: test23 (if it is available) , testbee and test.html

So, in Perl,

```
($user, $sys, $file) = ($source =~ /(\S*?)\@?(\S+?):?[^:]*?([^\/]+)$/);
```

for 1. this gives, $user = , $sys = test@testbee, $file = test.html
for 2. this gives, $user = , $sys = test, $file = test.html

Is there a way, I can just use one expression to get the user 'test' if it exists and nothing if it doesnt.

Comment: Are you trying do to this [`/(?:([^@\s]+)@)?([^\s:]*):.*\/(.*)/`](https://regex101.com/r/4Uij4s/1)?

Comment: @revo Actually I didn't see your comment before my answer finally both are same :)

Answer (score 2):

More maintainable solution:

```
use URI qw();
for my $str (qw(
    test23@testbee:/var/bee/
    testbee:/var/bee/test.html
)) {
    my $u = URI->new("ssh://$str");
    printf "user: %s  host: %s  path: %s\n",
        $u->user, $u->host, $u->path;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This here will always match the optional part as group 1, sometimes either `$1` or `$3` will be empty:

```
(?:(\w+)@)?(\w+):(?:\/\w+){2}\/((?:\w|\.)*)
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/s2ONxR/1)

If you want to skip more subdirectories, replace the `{2}` by `*`.

Comment: interesting..will look into this!